# Stack overflow error in console application

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I currently have a console application written in C# for production server environment. It's quite simple, but I've been testing it for +- 3 months now on my own server (semi-production, but not a disaster if the program fails). I've been getting stack overflow errors every few weeks or so, though.

Of course, pasting my entire source code here would be quite a long piece, so I will try to explain it the best I can: the program is in an infinite while loop (this is probably the cause of the issue), and it checks every second a few small things and prints to the console every so often (if no activity, every 15min, otherwise up-to every second).

Now why and how can I fix the stack overflow errors? Being able to run it for a couple weeks without issue may seem like a lot, but it is obviously not in a server production environment. My guess is that it's the fact I'm using a while loop, but what alternatives do I have?

Edit: here's a portion of the code:

```
int timeLoop = 0;
while (true)
{
  // If it has been +-10min since last read of messages file, read again
  if (timeLoop > 599)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " Reading messages...");
    messagesFile = File.ReadAllText(@"messages.cfg");
    messages = messagesFile.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    timeLoop = 0;
  }

  // For each message, check if time specified equals current time, if so say message globally.
  foreach (string x in messages)
  {
    string[] messageThis = x.Split('~');
    int typeLoop = 0;
    if (messageThis[2] != "no-loop")
      typeLoop = Convert.ToInt16(messageThis[2].Remove(0, 5));
    DateTime checkDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(messageThis[0], "HH:mm:ss", null);

    if (typeLoop == 0)
    {
      if (checkDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss") == DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
        publicMethods.sayGlobal(messageThis[1]);
      }
      else
      {
        DateTime originalDateTime = checkDateTime;
      do
      {
        checkDateTime = checkDateTime.AddHours(typeLoop);
        if (checkDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss") == DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
          publicMethods.sayGlobal(messageThis[1]);
      } while (checkDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss") != originalDateTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
    }
  }

  timeLoop++;
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Also, I forgot that I actually have this code on Github, which probably helps a lot. I know you shouldn't be using any links to code and have them here, so that's why I included the snippet above - but if you are interested in helping me out the repository is located [here](https://github.com/gdscei/ServerMessages). Another note - I know that doing it like this is not very accurate on timing - but this is not much of an issue at the moment.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? Does anything call itself recursively?

Comment: this exception won't be fixed for you if there is not any code

Comment: I can confirm that `while` loops, in and of themselves, do **not** cause stack overflows.

Comment: You are running this thing in background all the time. So the infinite loop actually IS the right solution. The question is how you implemented it.

Comment: Look for a recursive call -- a while loop does not cause a stack overflow.

Comment: Try to print out what is being called, either way somewhere control leaves the while loop and goes to another method, or maybe you initialize more and more local variables than you have memory for? Or you start more & more threads that don't end thus limiting stack space each thread untill you encounter an error.

Really, we don't have enough information to help you

Comment: @DylanMeeus "maybe you initialize more and more local variables than you have memory for": That might cause OutOfMemoryExceptions, but not StackOverflow exceptions.

Comment: @dcastro Yep, you're right. They are both caused due to an overflow on the stack though ^^

Comment: I've included a snippet of code and link to Github. I hope this helps out to figure out the issue. Unforunately, I do not have a stack trace, the error happens over weeks, and last time it happened I did not have any kind of logging or similiar, I simply get a not responding error from Windows and a stackoverflow error occured error in the console without trace.

Comment: can you provide publicMethods.sayGlobal(messageThis[1]);

Comment: and why don't use BackgroundWorker() for this work !

Comment: @Akrem it is simply a call to a function in a library and console log. If you would like to check that function out, it's in the GitHub repository under BattleNET.

Comment: @Akrem and about your comment on BackgroundWorker, this while loop executes in a seperate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BattleEyeClient.Connect` can call itself in some (failing) circumstances, and this method can be called by `sayGlobal` - so you probably want to change this code block (from line 98):

```
        catch
        {
            if (disconnectionType == BattlEyeDisconnectionType.ConnectionLost)
            {
                Disconnect(BattlEyeDisconnectionType.ConnectionLost);
                Connect();
                return BattlEyeConnectionResult.ConnectionFailed;
            }
            else
            {
                OnConnect(loginCredentials, BattlEyeConnectionResult.ConnectionFailed);
                return BattlEyeConnectionResult.ConnectionFailed;
            }
        }
```

Maybe keep track of how many reconnection attempts you make or transform this section of code so that *it* is a `while` loop rather than a recursive call during this failure mode.

---

Even worse, of course, is if that recursive `Connect` call succeeds, this `catch` block then returns `BattlEyeConnectionResult.ConnectionFailed` which it probably shouldn't.

Comment: I've seen the stackoverflow error mostly when this happened I recall, so this is probably it! Thank you, I will try this out.